In a module over a PID for every two elements there is an elements whose annihilator is the intersection of their annihilators
Let $A$ be a p.i.d. and $M$ an $A$-module. Let $x,y\in M$ and $\text{Ann}(x)=(m)$ and $\text{Ann}(y)=(n)$. We want to show there is a $z\in M$ such that $\text{Ann}(z)=(m)\cap(n)$. Since $A$ is a u.f.d. we can build $m_1,n_1$ such that $m_1n_1=\text{lcm}(m,n)$ and let $z=\frac{m}{m}_1x+\frac{n}{n_1}y$. I now want to show that $\text{Ann}(z)=(m_1n_1)$ but I don't know how to do this.
What I tried is to assume $s\in\text{Ann}(z)$. We have to prove that $m|s$ and $n|s$. We have $\frac{sm}{m_1}x+\frac{sn}{n_1}y=0$. If both terms had to be zero the rest would be easy but I'm not sure whether that's even true.

I recommend to name the variables differently. $m,n$ should be elements of $M$. Just saying this because I was quite confused when reading your approach for the first time. (But of course it's not necessary to rename these, from a  formal point of view.)

By the way, where did you find this statement? It doesn't look correct to me (without further assumptions on $M$).

@MartinBrandenburg What do you recommend I put instead of them?

@MartinBrandenburg My professor told me about this. I don't know where he found it himself. The special case for Abelian groups is well-known (e.g. see here). We actually completed the proof yesterday and I will post an answer to my question and then you could verify it.
